# InnerHTML for Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like JavaScript style innerHTML in Java. For instance, I want to get 'TRUE' from the string below:

```
String control = "<div class='myclass'>TRUE</div>";
```

But my pattern seems to be off as find() returns false. Ideas anyone?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">(.*?)<");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(control);

if(matcher.find()) {
    result = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Why not use jquery to do this or at least some dom selector rather than regexes?

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1702990

Comment: @Quirliom - you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of the question mark:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String control = "<div class='myclass'>TRUE</div>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">(.*)<");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(control);
    String result = null;
    if(matcher.find()) {
        result = matcher.group(1);
    }
    System.out.print(result);
}
```

BTW it would be better to learn how to use java's DOM objects and XPath classes.

Comment: Your BTW is the really the only way of doing it.

Comment: System.out.print(control.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""));

Comment: This is exactly what I need. DOM and XPath are too heavyweight. I'm not working with fully formed documents but rather snippets from a WCMS. The expected String 'should' never have nested tags. @Jeff Storey jquery is also out as this process occurs in a pre-rendering state on the server. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Jquery or if you really insist on doing it in Java, try using JSoup to strip out the HTML and return on the `safe` stuff